# How to have node.js listen for new sqlsrv rows in a table

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sqlsrv

Is there a way to listen for new **sqlsrv** data in **node.js** (or PHP 5.5) without having to poll the database constantly?  I am (obviously, I suppose) trying to have mssql notify my application when new data has been written without having to poll from JavaScript every few seconds.
I thought about something like:

(in a timer:)

`SELECT TOP 1 row_id FROM table`

`if returned row_id > what I last saw, do something`

but it seems inelegant...  thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: MySQL isn't really the right data store if what you want it real time data without polling. I've heard Postgres SQL supports this functionality and if they fit your data a document database would definitely allow for this. However, if you need to keep using MySQL polling is your only option :/

Comment: Brilliant. The perfect argument for why node.js is not as great as people like to pretend. Just because you use node.js rather than php or something else doesn't automatically make things real time. Buzzword defeated.

Comment: This project is using Microsoft SQL Server, PHP and node.js.  I am not raising a question regarding the suitability of these tools for this task I am trying to make the best of it.  Thank you.  :-)

Comment: Sorry, I misread mssql as mysql. You may want to check out [Change Tracking](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280462(v=sql.105).aspx) in SQL Server. I don't know if it will actually simplify things for you, but it's probably the closest you can get.

Answer (score 0):

you can run service [mssql2amqp](https://github.com/event-driven-arch/mssql2amqp), then connect to amqp brocker (rabbitMQ) and listen specified queue [rabbitmq sample](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html).